# Set theory: Lexicographic ordering and chain proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be partially ordered sets, and let $C$ and $D$ be chains of $A$ and $B$, respectively. If $A \times B$ is ordered lexicographically, prove that $C \times D$ is a chain of $A \times B$.

My attempt

for all $c_1,c_2 \in C, c_1 \le c_2$ or $c_2 \le c_1$

for all $d_1,d_2 \in D, d_1 \le d_2$ or $d_2 \le d_1$

we have to show that $C \times D$ is a chain of $A \times B$.

$\implies \forall (c_1,d_1),(c_2,d_2) \in C \times D$,

$(c_1,d_1) \le (c_2,d_2)$ or $(c_2,d_2) \le (c_1,d_1)$

and I think I need to use the fact that $A \times B$ is ordered lexicographically but am having trouble making the connection.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

I have made some addition but am not sure if this proves the question.

Since every $c_1,c_2 \in A$ and every $d_1,d_2 \in B$, and $A \times B$ is ordered lexicographically, we have that

$c_1 \lt c_2$ or

$c_1=c_2$ and $d_1 \le d_2$

$\iff (c_1,d_1) \le (c_2,d_2)$

Hence it follows that  $C \times D$ is a chain of $A \times B$.

Comment: What if $c_1 > c_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(c_1,d_1), (c_2,d_2) \in C \times D \subseteq A \times B$, then $c_1,c_2 \in C$, which is a chain and $d_1,d_2 \in D$, which is a chain.

- If $c_1 < c_2$, then $(c_1,d_1) < (c_2,d_2)$
- If $c_1 > c_2$, then $(c_1,d_1) > (c_2,d_2)$
- If $c_1 = c_2$, then do the same with $d_1$ and $d_2$

Comment: Consider your second bullet point.

Comment: A typo due to copy paste. Shame on me :) Thanks @DHMO

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So for the first and second bullet points, do you assume that $d_1=d_2$?

Comment: @CrusoJames No. If $c_1 < c_2$ or $c_1 > c_2$ then it doesn't matter what happens between $d_1$ and $d_2$. That's how the lexicographic order works.

Comment: Oh okay I understand it now! The book in the definition only had the case when $c_1 \lt c_2$ so I didn't consider the second bullet point. So i guess the reverse inequality sign also is true obviously right?

Comment: @CrusoJames Yes, it's just a matter of swapping the elements in the expression.